Creating a categorical data from two columns in pandas
I'm trying to practice coding again and currently having problems with figuring out why my function doesn't work.
Here's my sample Table for reference:



diastolic
systolic




80.0
130.0


77.0
126.0


92.0
152.0


76.0
147.0


70.0
127.0


64.0
119.0


72.0
135.0


84.0
137.0


85.0
165.0


81.0
156.0



and here's the function I created to categorize the data:
def blood_pressure_cat(diastolic, systolic):
    """
    diastolic: float
    systolic: float
    """
    
    if systolic <= 90 and diastolic <= 60:
        return "Hypotension"
    elif systolic < 120 and diastolic < 80:
        return "Normal"
    elif systolic < 130 and diastolic < 80:
        return "Elevated"
    elif systolic < 140 and diastolic < 90:
        return "Stage 1"
    elif systolic < 180 and diastolic < 90:
        return "Stage 2"
    elif systolic >= 180 and diastolic >= 90:
        return "Hypertensive Crisis"
    else:
        return np.nan

This is how I execute my function:
blood_pressure_cat(DF["diastolic"], DF["systolic"])

And getting this error:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

If I change the "and"s in that function I get this one instead:
Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Can somebody help me understand why it is not working or if there's any alternative way to run this code?

A very simple approach would be to vectorize your function, for example by decorating the function:
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def blood_pressure_cat(diastolic, systolic):
    """
    diastolic: float
    systolic: float
    """
    
    if systolic <= 90 and diastolic <= 60:
        return "Hypotension"
    elif systolic < 120 and diastolic < 80:
        return "Normal"
    elif systolic < 130 and diastolic < 80:
        return "Elevated"
    elif systolic < 140 and diastolic < 90:
        return "Stage 1"
    elif systolic < 180 and diastolic < 90:
        return "Stage 2"
    elif systolic >= 180 and diastolic >= 90:
        return "Hypertensive Crisis"
    else:
        return np.nan

blood_pressure_cat(DF["diastolic"], DF["systolic"])

Output:
array(['Stage 1', 'Elevated', 'nan', 'Stage 2', 'Elevated', 'Normal',
       'Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2'], dtype='<U8')

Note that the returned NaNs will be strings.
To get real NaNs, instead of a decorator, manually wrap the function and pass the otypes=[object] parameter:
blood_pressure_cat = np.vectorize(blood_pressure_cat, otypes=[object])

blood_pressure_cat(DF["diastolic"], DF["systolic"])

Output:
array(['Stage 1', 'Elevated', nan, 'Stage 2', 'Elevated', 'Normal',
       'Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2'], dtype=object)

As a new column:
DF['cat'] = blood_pressure_cat(DF["diastolic"], DF["systolic"])

Also be aware that this vectorization is a wrapper around a python loop.
Therefore you could also use pure python with zip:
DF['cat'] = [blood_pressure_cat(d, s) for d,s in zip(DF['diastolic'], DF['systolic'])]

This gives a similar result than using apply with axis=1 but avoids creating a Series for each row (which is expensive).
Output:
   diastolic  systolic       cat
0       80.0     130.0   Stage 1
1       77.0     126.0  Elevated
2       92.0     152.0       NaN
3       76.0     147.0   Stage 2
4       70.0     127.0  Elevated
5       64.0     119.0    Normal
6       72.0     135.0   Stage 1
7       84.0     137.0   Stage 1
8       85.0     165.0   Stage 2
9       81.0     156.0   Stage 2


Thanks man, not only you solve my problem but also provide some ways to optimize data processing

One possible solution is to use DataFrame.apply with axis=1 parameter:
df["bloold_pressure_cat"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: blood_pressure_cat(row["diastolic"], row["systolic"]), axis=1
)
print(df)

Prints:
   diastolic  systolic bloold_pressure_cat
0       80.0     130.0             Stage 1
1       77.0     126.0            Elevated
2       92.0     152.0                 NaN
3       76.0     147.0             Stage 2
4       70.0     127.0            Elevated
5       64.0     119.0              Normal
6       72.0     135.0             Stage 1
7       84.0     137.0             Stage 1
8       85.0     165.0             Stage 2
9       81.0     156.0             Stage 2


I think the method you're looking for is dataframe method .apply().
In your example you pass pd.Series objects in blood_pressure_cat() function (here blood_pressure_cat(DF["diastolic"], DF["systolic"])) but the function expects float args.
You can use blood_pressure_cat function in .apply() method for example like this:
df.apply(lambda x: blood_pressure_cat(x.diastolic, x.systolic), axis = 1)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    'diastolic': [80.0, 77.0, 92.0, 76.0, 70.0, 64.0, 72.0, 84.0, 85.0, 81.0],
    'systolic': [130.0, 126.0, 152.0, 147.0, 127.0, 119.0, 135.0, 137.0, 165.0, 156.0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def blood_pressure_category(diastolic, systolic):
    """
    diastolic: float
    systolic: float
    """
    if systolic <= 90 and diastolic <= 60:
        return "Hypotension"
    elif systolic < 120 and diastolic < 80:
        return "Normal"
    elif systolic < 130 and diastolic < 80:
        return "Elevated"
    elif systolic < 140 and diastolic < 90:
        return "Stage 1"
    elif systolic < 180 and diastolic < 90:
        return "Stage 2"
    elif systolic >= 180 and diastolic >= 90:
        return "Hypertensive Crisis"
    else:
        return np.nan


df['category'] = df.apply(lambda row: blood_pressure_category(
                          row['diastolic'], row['systolic']), axis=1)

print(df)
"""
  diastolic  systolic  category
0       80.0     130.0   Stage 1
1       77.0     126.0  Elevated
2       92.0     152.0       NaN
3       76.0     147.0   Stage 2
4       70.0     127.0  Elevated
5       64.0     119.0    Normal
6       72.0     135.0   Stage 1
7       84.0     137.0   Stage 1
8       85.0     165.0   Stage 2
9       81.0     156.0   Stage 2

"""

